# bash: check if a particular git repository has github as remote repo?

Tags: git, bash, github

I was wondering if it is, at all, possible to check if a git repository is using github.com as remote repository, and get the url for it via bash?

Any help will be appreciated.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can try a:

```
git remote -v show
```

And see if a "`github`" address pops up in set of tracked repositories.

Comment: Of course, if the user is using a ssh-alias (like me) for github.com, it may turn out with another name. But I suppose you are doing this for your own repositories, and then you should now.

Answer (score 0):

Doing a `git config -l` works as well in the `work-tree`
However, it still isn't successful for ssh-alias, as Paulo Ebermann pointed out.

**Sample Output:**

```
remote.origin.url=git@github.com:nikhgupta/cli-poster.git
remote.origin.fetch=+refs/heads/*:refs/remotes/origin/*
branch.master.remote=origin
branch.master.merge=refs/heads/master
```